# Transform function to a character string without losing comments

Tags: r

I want to transform functions to a character strings. I can't directly transform class function to a class character, thus I'm using `function` to `list` to `character` logic. However, `list` removes comments from functions.

Example:

```
foo <- function() {
    1 + 1
}
# Can't use as.character(foo), thus:
as.character(list(foo))
    "function () \n{\n    1 + 1\n}"
```

However, if function contains comment then it gets removed

```
bar <- function() {
    # sum
    1 + 1
}
as.character(list(bar))
    "function () \n{\n    1 + 1\n}"
```

Question: Why list removes comments from functions and how to save them? Or what is a better way to transform functions to character strings?

**Edit:**
 Suggestion by MrFlick to use `capture.output` works for interactive R session. However, if use `code.R`:

```
bar <- function() {
    # sum
    1 + 1
}
# collectMetaData()
print(paste0(capture.output(print(bar)), collapse="\n"))
```

And try to run it with `Rscript code.R` my output is still: `"function () \n{\n    1 + 1\n}"`

Comment: Try `paste0(capture.output(print(bar)), collapse="\n")`. That avoids the `list()`. These a discrepancy with `print.function(...useSource=)` I think because the compiled function doesn't contain comments. The comments are tracked by the `srcref`/`srcfile` attribute only.

Comment: I had to run to catch a bus so I didn't have time to dig further at my computer. If no one else creates an answer, I'll expand when I can.

Comment: @MrFlick capture.output seems to be what I need, but it doesn't work when using `Rscript code.R`, functions get saved without comments there. ie., if I run code interactively `capture.output` produces wanted output.

Comment: Receipt probably isn't going to capture the source for functions. If you need this to work non-interactively, the make that clear in your question because that does add a challenge. But this makes me wonder what you are *really* trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea, why you'd want to do that. This looks like an xy problem. Anyway, you seem to want to deparse the function:

```
bar <- function() {
  # sum
  1 + 1
}

paste(deparse(bar, control = "useSource"), collapse = "\n")
#[1] "function() {\n  # sum\n  1 + 1\n}"
```